# Tab navigation in bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap tab navigation that is working fine on page index.php, Currently when i click non any tab the url of the page remains same, i wish to know that is there a way i can change the url of the page, whenever a tab is clicked so that i can keep a track of which tab is selected by user.

E.g: if user clicks on tab A then the url may change into
index.php?tab=A
OR
if user clicks on tab B then the url may change into
index.php?tab=B

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li class="active col-md-3">
        <a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab" > A </a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab" > B </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1">
</div>


<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2">
</div>
```

Comment: You want the page to reload when the tab is clicked ? Because `?tab=` is query string.

Comment: You only want to track which tab was clicked, is it so?

Comment: you have php/jquery tags with no relevant code to support the question/code. to answer this, you need a mod rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `a` tags with this :

```
    <a href="index.php#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab" > A </a>
    <a href="index.php#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab" > B </a>
```

Did you try this ?

Comment: it is not changing the url

Answer (score 0):

Get the clicked tab using "shown.bs.tab" event which fires after tab gets active, and save clicked tab "href" to local storage, so that later make it active by getting it from local storage and open it manually.

```js
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
               // save current clicked tab in local storage
                localStorage.setItem('lastActiveTab', $(this).attr('href'));
            });
            //get last active tab from local storage
            var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastActiveTab');
alert(lastTab +"tab was last active")
            if (lastTab) {
                $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```